# Automatic Canny Edge Detection in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine, image-processing, canny-operator

I'm searching for an automatic detection of the lower and upper value for the Canny edge detection function in OpenCvSharp.

I found the following code, but unfortunately it isn't written in C# (I'm programming in Unity). I don't know how I can write this in Unity (C#):

```
lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
```

Could somebody help me with this?

(Source: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/)

```
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)
    # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)
    # return the edged image
    return edged
```

Comment: I do not understand why that is so hard. The equations are simple. Do you not program in C#? If not, how did you have code for the Canny edge detection. Please clarify your question and your coding ability and your code for doing the Canny edge detection. Code and arguments for Canny work differently on different systems. So those values may not be appropriate for your Canny code.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify enough. The thing I don't understand is what does the max, min do?

Comment: If your snippet is written in C++, the `max` and `min` functions receive two arguments: `fun(a,b)`. In the case of `max`, the function returns the largest of `a` and `b`. For `min`, it returns the smallest. So, in that snippet, for finding the value of `lower`, you first select the value that is the largest between `0` and `(1.0 - sigma) * v`. What is `sigma` and `v`? - I don't know. After you select that value, you cast it from (I'm guessing a `float/double`?) to an `int`. And that's the value for `lower`.

Comment: Sigma is provided as an argument in the range 0 to 1. It is just a fraction between 0 and 1. V is the value returned from the median value of the whole input image image. So the formula is finding a range of (1-sigma)*V = median_value-0.33*median_value to (1+sigma)*V = median_value+0.33*median_value and then ensuring that those values do not exceed 0 or 255 by using the min() and max() functions as described by ` eldesgraciado` Another option for sigma is to use the standard deviation (in range 0 to 1) of the whole input image as the argument rather than a simple fraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = np.median(image)
```

There is no built in function to [compute the median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median). An easy, (but non optimal) way is to [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8) the pixels and picking the middle value.

```
int(...)
```

Convert from double to int by `(int)Math.Round(...)` or by just `(int)...`

```
min(...)
```

In c# this is Math.Min(...)

The rest is just basic arithmetic that should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, now I understand the code. For the Median I found a function in OpenCv, which is more efficient.